# Foreach loop: split elements in groups of five and six

Tags: php, html

I'm using a foreach loop to output images fetched from the Instagram API. 
I want to split the outputted images in groups of **four** and **five** and in addition to that add a div element to each group except the last one where 2 div's should be added, so I get the following structure:

```
<div class="group>
    <div class="extra"> </div>
    <img/>
    <img/>
    <img/>
    <img/>
</div> <!-- Close group of 5 -->
<div class="group>
    <div class="extra"> </div>
    <img/>
    <img/>
    <img/>
    <img/>
    <img/>
</div> <!-- Close group of 6 -->
<div class="group>
    <div class="extra"> </div>
    <img/>
    <img/>
    <img/>
    <div class="extra"> </div>
</div> <!-- Close group of 5 -->
```

By using modulus in the loop I've manage to group the elements with the correct number of items in each group, **but** when I try to add the extra div to each group it breaks the counting and I'm no longer getting the correct number of elements grouped together. The code I'm currently using to print out the images (12 in total):

```
  <div class="group"> <!-- Open group-wrapper -->

  $count = 0;

  foreach($decoded_results['data'] as $item) {

      if ($count  % 11 == 0 || $count % 11 == 5 ) {
          echo '<div class="extra"> </div>'; 
          echo '</div> <div class="group">';
      }

      echo '<a target="_blank" href=' .$link_url. '>';
      echo '<div class="img-wrapper">';
      echo '<img src="'.$image_link.'" /> </div> </a>';

      $count++;   
  }
```

Any suggestion how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be enough to point you in the correct direction:

```
<div class='group'>
    <div class='extra'></div>
    <?php
    $i = 1;
    $j = 1;
    $step = 4;
    $count = count($decoded_results['data']);
    foreach($decoded_results['data'] as $k => $v) {
        ?>
        <a target='_blank' href='<?php echo $v;?>'>
            <div class='img-wrapper'>
                <img src='<?php echo $v;?>' />
            </div>
        </a>
        <?php
        if (($j % $step) == 0 && $i < $count) {
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class='group'>
            <div class="extra"></div>
            <?php
            $step = ($step == 4) ? 5: 4;
            $j = 0;
        }
        $j++;   
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
    <div class='extra'></div>
</div>
```

On a side note you should be aware that having a `div` (block element) inside an `a` (inline element) isn't exactly semantic HTML, but still widely accepted nowadays. I personally tend to avoid this and can do by using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP use the array_chunk() function 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php